# How to get table structure in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, structure

I want to know the structure of a table. How I can do it in CodeIgniter. Using database class I got 'Invalid SQL Statement' error when I ran `$this->db->query('desc mytable');`

Comment: `$this->db->query('DESCRIBE mytable');` doesn't work?

Comment: not work. Seem the query function only accept SELECT keyword

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
$fields = $this->db->list_fields('table_name');
foreach ($fields as $field)
{
   echo $field;
}
```

From [manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/metadata.html#list-the-fields-in-a-table)

Comment: Thanks, This is perfectly match what I need.

Comment: Fazri, the answer by @Omar Alvarado below should have been your accepted answer.  You asked how to get the _structure_ of a table, not just the list of fields.

Comment: @OliverWilliams Maybe you're right, but the answer you're suggesting is six years too late. :)

Comment: Nevertheless.. :)

Answer (score 2):

For more descriptive information, you should use

```
$fields = $this->db->field_data('table_name');
```

You're going to get something like this foreach field in fields as stdClass

```
name = "id"
type = "int"
max_length = 11
default = null
primary_key = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For Get Table Schema in CodeIgniter query:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTableName');
$queryResultArray = $query->result_array();
print_r( $queryResultArray[0]['Create Table'] );
```